# How do I set a variable as the name of a struct?

Tags: c, variables, struct

so right now im making a program that involves creating numerous structures named after airport destinations but i encountered a problem where i don't seem to find a solution. How can I give the name of my structure using a variable instead of the string itself? as in:

```
struct airport {
    char name;
    int capacity;
}

int main(void)
{
    id = "dubai";
    struct airport id;
}
```

and i want that to create the struct:

```
struct airport dubai;
```

Comment: You can't do that in C. Why do you want to do it anyway?

Comment: @l3x: There are good applications for this. But that would require dynamically typed languages like Python.

Comment: Change your `name` field to a pointer or array.

Comment: All the names of variables are fixed at compile time. After that, the names of variables stop to exist (except in symbol files for debuggers).

Comment: Use a map/dictionary. But you have to code it yourself (and it is much less comfortable to use than in dynamically typed languages).

Comment: @l3x because in my program i want to create an airport with a different id name every time a command is executed so that in the end there are a lot of struct airports.

Comment: Define a set of `enum` values using the unique airport codes such as `enum {LHR, LGW, PVG, ...}` and so on. Then use them as array indices, such as `airport_array[LHR]`.

Comment: What would you do with this name? Show some pseudocode.

Comment: ...although I am not sure my comment will help, since your example "code" shows great naivety as to how to code in C.

Comment: Maybe you can take advantage of compiler directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example of a module:

```
struct airport{
    char *name;
    int capacity;
} all_airports[MAX+AIRPORTS];
int nextAirport;

struct airport *newAirport(char *name, int capacity)
{
    all_airports[nextAirport].name= malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(all_airports[nextAirport].name, name);
    all_airports[nextAirport].capacity= capacity;
    return(&all_airports[nextAirport++]);
}
```

now you can create an airport with:

```
int main(){
    struct airport *myAirport= newAirport("Dubai",1000);
}
```

and later go through the array to find your airport using `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Since id is a variable a member and you are trying to declare a variable as a variable. And in  any programming language you can not declare same variable twice.

Why you want to do this and what is the exactly need? May be we can solve the problem, if we identified what logic you are implementing here.

Look variables declared in the memory at compile time and the value in the variables come at run time. And if you do this, you can’t because **duabi** will be assigned at run time while s**tructure variable** will be declared at compile time.